# How to parse json parsing Using GSON in android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using `GSON` for parse Json data. My Json data is below:

```
{
    "count": "12",
    "colbreak": 1,
    "name": "unary rels",
    "score": "9090",
    "Words": [
        {
            "count": 6,
            "word": "prp_għaċ-",
            "name": "prp_għaċ-",
            "score": 9.1,
            "Words": "kol",
            "seek": 2231297
        }
    ],
    "seek": 0
}
```

**GsonParse.java**

```
public class GsonParse {


 @SerializedName("count")
 public String count;

 @SerializedName("colbreak")
 public String colbreak;

 @SerializedName("name")
 public String count;
 @SerializedName("score")
 public String score;

 @SerializedName("Words")
 public List<Words> mWords = new ArrayList<Words>();

 @SerializedName("seek")
 public String seek;
}
```

I am using below method to parse this JSON data.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> JsonParse(T t, String response) {
        // convert String into InputStream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        JsonReader reader;
        ArrayList<T> lcs = new ArrayList<T>();
        try {
            reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {

                T cse = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, t.getClass());
                lcs.add(cse);
            }

            reader.endObject();

            /*
             * reader.nextName(); reader.nextString(); reader.nextName();
             * reader.nextString();
             */
            reader.close();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (ArrayList<T>) lcs;
    }
```

I am facing below error.

```
03-31 10:14:26.968: E/AndroidRuntime(18578): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 1 column 73
```

Comment: Please post error logs.

Comment: Please post `Words` class as well.

Comment: @Sid how to parse this json string?

Answer (score 21):

you could try reading the gson value like this:

```
try {
      AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
  InputStream ims = assetManager.open("file.txt");

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);

  GsonParse gsonObj = gson.fromJson(reader, GsonParse.class);

     }catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Assuming that you are just receiving this one block and not a list. And also this data  is currently in a file in the assets folder. You can change it to the stream you want to read it from.

The class you use should look like:

**GsonParse.class**

```
public class GsonParse {
 @SerializedName("count")
 private String count;

 @SerializedName("colbreak")
 private String colbreak;

 @SerializedName("name")
 private String name;

 @SerializedName("score")
 private String score;

 @SerializedName("Words")
 private List<Words> mWords = new ArrayList<Words>();

 @SerializedName("seek")
 private String seek;

public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getColbreak() {
    return colbreak;
}

public void setColbreak(String colbreak) {
    this.colbreak = colbreak;
}

private String getName() {
    return name;
}

private void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public List<Words> getmWords() {
    return mWords;
}

public void setmWords(List<Words> mWords) {
    this.mWords = mWords;
}

public String getSeek() {
    return seek;
}

public void setSeek(String seek) {
    this.seek = seek;
}
}
```

**Words.class**

```
public class Words {
@SerializedName(value ="count")
private String count;
@SerializedName(value="word")
private String word;
@SerializedName(value="score")
private String name;
@SerializedName(value="Words")
private String words;
@SerializedName(value="seek")
private String seek;

    public String getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public String getWord() {
    return word;
}
public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getWords() {
    return words;
}
public void setWords(String words) {
    this.words = words;
}
public String getSeek() {
    return seek;
}
public void setSeek(String seek) {
    this.seek = seek;
}
}
```

there is a parameter missing in words.class, you could add it .

GSON does not directly support UTF-8 characters. so when receiving the response using http, you will have to convert that to utf-8 form in the response of http itself.

you could try using:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(objectToEncode);
byte[] utf8JsonString = jsonString.getBytes("UTF8");
responseToClient.write(utf8JsonString, 0, utf8JsonString.Length);
```

Comment: Gson don't use get/swt why make them? At least if you want to add get/set make fields private

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes gson doesnt use them but just in order to get the data :).. correct they should be private. I simple picked the user's classes :).. il change that.. :)

Answer (score 9):

Hello use below gradle lib

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Json Class

```
import java.util.List;
public class GsonParse{

/**
 * count : 12
 * colbreak : 1
 * name : unary rels
 * score : 9090
 * Words : [{"count":6,"word":"prp_għaċ-","name":"prp_għaċ-","score":9.1,"Words":"kol","seek":2231297}]
 * seek : 0
 */

private String count;
private int colbreak;
private String name;
private String score;
private int seek;
/**
 * count : 6
 * word : prp_għaċ-
 * name : prp_għaċ-
 * score : 9.1
 * Words : kol
 * seek : 2231297
 */

private List<WordsBean> Words;

public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public int getColbreak() {
    return colbreak;
}

public void setColbreak(int colbreak) {
    this.colbreak = colbreak;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public int getSeek() {
    return seek;
}

public void setSeek(int seek) {
    this.seek = seek;
}

public List<WordsBean> getWords() {
    return Words;
}

public void setWords(List<WordsBean> Words) {
    this.Words = Words;
}

public static class WordsBean {
    private int count;
    private String word;
    private String name;
    private double score;
    private String Words;
    private int seek;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getWords() {
        return Words;
    }

    public void setWords(String Words) {
        this.Words = Words;
    }

    public int getSeek() {
        return seek;
    }

    public void setSeek(int seek) {
        this.seek = seek;
    }
}
```

}

Calling API put response in below code and Retrive Data

```
GsonParse gsonparse = gson.fromJson(response, GsonParse.class);
//gsonparse.getWords() // It will returns list of Words
//Also do loop and get more data using data
gsonparse.getColbreak();
gsonparse.getSeek();
for (GsonParse.WordsBean data:gsonparse.getWords())
{

    data.getName();

}
```

hope it will help to you..

Comment: while getting data its give warning

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
@SerializedName("name")
public String count;
```

**with**

```
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
```

I guess the issue is you are using `public String count;` for both `@SerializedName("count")` and `@SerializedName("name")`

Thanks.

Comment: it surprises me but, why did the user not get a compile time error saying that count has already been defined ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("responseData");
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<AllUsers>>(){}.getType();
List<AllUsers> allUserses = 
    new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonarray.toString(), listType);

for(AllUsers user: allUserses){
         allUsersDao.insertOrReplace(user);
}
```

Comment: Try to format your code and I guess that some explications wont do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

There are many thing missing in your code..

Please look at below code and try this code..

```
import java.util.List;

public class GsonParse {

    public GsonParse() {
    }

    public String count = "";
    public String colbreak = "";
    public String name = "";
    public String score = "";
    public int seek = 0;
    List<WordsData> Words;

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getColbreak() {
        return colbreak;
    }

    public void setColbreak(String colbreak) {
        this.colbreak = colbreak;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getSeek() {
        return seek;
    }

    public void setSeek(int seek) {
        this.seek = seek;
    }

    public List<WordsData> getWords() {
        return Words;
    }

    public void setWords(List<WordsData> words) {
        Words = words;
    }

    public class WordsData {

        public WordsData() {
        }

        public int count = 0;
        public String word = "";
        public String name = "";
        public double score = 0.0;
        public String Words = "";
        public int seek = 0;

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(double score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getWords() {
            return Words;
        }

        public void setWords(String words) {
            Words = words;
        }

        public int getSeek() {
            return seek;
        }

        public void setSeek(int seek) {
            this.seek = seek;
        }
    }

}
```

For more detail look at this [example](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/)

Comment: @dipali, you only need to use the "@serializedName" if the JSON field name is different from your instance variable name. gson is smart enough to figure it out when the field name matches the instance variable name exactly.