# Read / Parse JSON objects from .ser file in Android

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a file in my sdcard which extension is abc.ser  and the file contain JSON objects like

```
{"music":"abc","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"}
{"music":"xyz","highqualityavailable":"false","cacheable":"true"}
{"music":"aaa","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"}
{"music":"bbb","highqualityavailable":"false","cacheable":"true"}
{"music":"ccc","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"}
```

the file contain JSON objects but not the proper format of JSON how can i read or parse it in my app i have already read the string in file but don,t know how to convert it to a POJO

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                File file = new File(root+"/tmp/playerSongsString.ser");

                if (file.exists()) {


                    FileInputStream stream = null;

                    try {

                        stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                        MappedByteBuffer bb =    fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
                      /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
                        jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jString);

                        Log.d("json:",jString);




                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: It will simplify your task a lot if you could fix these files to have correct JSON formatted data.

Comment: yes i know but the file is created by some other app and i have no control over it

Comment: If you are sure file size is small, you can simply use  `JSONObject object = new JSONObject("["+jString+"]");`

Comment: To parse the JSONObject to POJO you can refer [this tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

First change you JSON data it's not in correct JSON format...

[{"music":"abc","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"},
{"music":"xyz","highqualityavailable":"false","cacheable":"true"},{"music":"aaa","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"},{"music":"bbb","highqualityavailable":"false","cacheable":"true"},{"music":"ccc","highqualityavailable":"true","cacheable":"true"}]

Then after convert string to JSON array.

More details : [How to parse json parsing Using GSON in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android)

Comment: i could append the square bracket but i don,t have comma,s in between objects as well

Comment: If you don't append commas between two objects then it will not consider as JSON Array.

Answer (score 0):

> This python code is only for converting .ser file into .json file

Files : [Opening files from this repository](https://github.com/imvickykumar999/Civilisation-Script-Translator/blob/main/translator)

```
with open('first-letters-root.ser', encoding="utf8") as f:
    w = f.read()
    
y = w.split('i:')[1:]
d = {}

for k,i in enumerate(y):
    j = i.split(';')[1].split(':')
    d[k] = j[-1]

import json
with open('first-letters-root.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)

info = open('first-letters-root.json')
res = json.load(info)
print(res)
```