# How to parse json using gson ?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can i get the time or the text 
of this json 
http://www.mocky.io/v2/58889af52600007c1d966456
somebody can help me ???

Comment: That _somebody_ could be _you_, if you put enough try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json parsing Using GSON in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
public String parse(String jsonLine) {
  JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
  JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
  jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
  JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");
  jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
  String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString();
  return result;
} //jsonLine refer to json
```

Comment: The OP asked for a solution using GSON.