# Android Volley does not loop through the whole JSON Objects

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Help guys, I am trying to parse this nested JSON Objects. When I checked the logcat it does not iterate to the next JSONObject of pasta. It only shows the first JSONObject of

"name" : "creamy bacon mushroom",
"details" : "", 
"price" : "",
"image" : { "url" : "" }

after that it infinitely loops over and over again.

This is my JSON:

```
[ 
{ 
    "food" : {
        "pasta" : [
            {
                "name" : "Creamy Bacon Mushroom",
                "price" : 170,
                "details" : "Creamyyy",
                "image" : {
                    "url" : "/SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "name" : "Vigan Longganisa Penne",
                "price" : 169,
                "details" : "Vigannnnn",
                "image" : {
                    "url" : "/SAD/uploads/food/images/2/food_pasta_viganlonganissapenne.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "name" : "Spanish Sardine Pesto",
                "price" : 168,
                "details" : "Spanishhhhh",
                "image" : {
                    "url" : "/SAD/uploads/food/images/3/food_pasta_spanishsardinepesto.jpg"
                }
            }
        ]

    }

}
```

]

This is my code:

```
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
               JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
               for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   JSONObject jsonObjectFood = jsonObject.getJSONObject("food");
                   JSONArray jsonArrayPasta = jsonObjectFood.getJSONArray("pasta");
                   Log.d(StringConfig.LOG_TAG, jsonArrayPasta.toString());

                   for(int j=0; j<jsonArrayPasta.length();i++){
                       JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayPasta.getJSONObject(j);
                       String jsonName = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                       String jsonPrice = jsonObject1.getString("price");
                       String jsonDetails = jsonObject1.getString("details");

                       JSONObject jsonObjectImage = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("image");
                       String jsonImage = jsonObjectImage.getString("url");


                       Log.d(StringConfig.LOG_TAG, "name : " + jsonName);
                       Log.d(StringConfig.LOG_TAG, "price : " + jsonPrice);
                       Log.d(StringConfig.LOG_TAG, "details : " + jsonDetails);
                       Log.d(StringConfig.LOG_TAG, "imageUrl : " + jsonImage);
                   }


               }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       }
   });
   requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

This is my logcat:

```
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl : /SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl : /SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl : /SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl : /SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl : /SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
07-28 14:54:53.691 6222-6222/? D/SAD: imageUrl :
```

/SAD/uploads/food/images/1/food_pasta_creamybaconmushroom.jpg
    07-28 14:54:53.692 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy
    07-28 14:54:53.692 6222-6222/? D/SAD: name : Creamy Bacon Mushroom
    07-28 14:54:53.692 6222-6222/? D/SAD: price : 170
    07-28 14:54:53.692 6222-6222/? D/SAD: details : Creamyyy

Comment: Problem in **i++**

Answer (score 1):

Change **i++** to **j++** in inner **for loop**

Comment: Thanks Anil :) I didn't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON format to parse JSON. you can see my answer [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android/39848532#39848532). I hope it will help you.