# How to parse this Json with no object name

Tags: android, json

```
{ 
   "quote": "To understand the heart and mind of a person, look not at 
   what he has already achieved, but at what he aspires to.",
   "author": "Kahlil Gibran (1883-1931)"
 }
```

How to parse this with no any object name

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to parse json object

Simple way

```
JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
String quote = myJson. getString("quote");
String author = myJson. getString("author");
```

Another and recomented way is parse json using Gson
For this you can refer below links

[How to parse json parsing Using GSON in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android)

https://www.journaldev.com/2321/gson-example-tutorial-parse-json

Answer (score 0):

How to do it ?

- If you meet `{}` in your code , you can use `JSONObject` to parse it .
- If you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `JSONArray` to parse it .
- And if you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `for loop` to get value in it .
- And you should use `try catch` in your code .

Try this .

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
        String quote = jsonObject.getString("quote");
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal json.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(your_json);
String quote = json.getString("quote");
String author = json.getString("author");
```