# Retrieving a single deep down array in JSON

Tags: java, android, json

So here is the JSON

```
{
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "images": {
        "image": [
      {...
```

I want to access the image array. I was wondering if the following code was the best way to do it:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("response");

JSONObject jsonObjectData = new JSONObject(jsonResponse.toString());
JSONObject jsonData = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("data");

JSONObject jsonObjectImages = new JSONObject(jsonData.toString());
JSONObject jsonImages = jsonObjectImages.getJSONObject("images");

JSONObject jsonObjectImage = new JSONObject(jsonImages.toString());
JSONArray jsonImageArray = jsonObjectImage.getJSONArray("image");
```

I feel like this requires a lot of time for a simple task. Does anyone have a more "engineered" solution? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try Gson to parse data

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753719/how-to-parse-json-parsing-using-gson-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot for every answers, i appreciate the help guys!
Bless you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not chain the getJSONObject function?

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject("jsonString");
JSONObject jsonImages = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("data")....
```

Comment: I'll try that, sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not the best way to do it. You keep converting from `JSONObject`s to `String`s and then back to `JSONObject`s again. You should be able do:

```
JSONArray jsonImageArray = new JSONObject(jsonString)
    .getJSONObject("response")
    .getJSONObject("data")
    .getJSONObject("images")
    .getJSONArray("image");
```

Even if you just remove all of the `toString` calls, it becomes a lot more concise (but I would still favour the above example):

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("response");
JSONObject jsonData = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject jsonImages = jsonData.getJSONObject("images");
JSONArray jsonImageArray = jsonImages.getJSONArray("image");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply combine all these statements in the following way:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonImageArray = jsonObjectResponse.getJsonObject("data")
                              .getJsonObject("images")
                              .getJsonArray("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray imageArray = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("response")
     .getJSONObject("data")
     .getJSONObject("images")
     .getJSONArray("image")
```

Hope it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can user chain calls:

```
String jsonString = "{\"response\":{\"data\":{\"images\":{\"image\":[]}}}}";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray image = json.getJSONObject("response") 
                      .getJSONObject("data")
                      .getJSONObject("images")
                      .getJSONArray("image");
```

E.g. your `image` objects like `{"title":"Some image","url":"http://..."}`, so:

```
JSONObject firstImage = image.getJSONObject(0);
String url = firstImage.getString("url");
```

Or you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Your classes:

```
class ServerAnswer {
    private Response response;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}

class Response {
    private Data data;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}

class Images {
    @SerializedName("image")
    private Image[] images;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}

class Image {
    private String url, title;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

And parse:

```
ServerAnswer answer = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ServerAnswer.class);

Image[] images = answer.getResponse().getData().getImages().getImagesArray();
Image firstImage = images[0];
String url = firstImage.getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
   public class Images {
        @SerializedName("image")
        public ArrayList<String> image;
   }

   public class Data {
        @SerializedName("images")
        public Images images;
   }

   public class Response {
        @SerializedName("data")
        public Data data;
   }

   public class MyData {
        @SerializedName("response")
        public Response response;
   }
```

then

```
MyData data = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, MyData.class);
```

I think this is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

```
JSONArray jsonResponseArray = new JSONObject(strJson).getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("images").getJSONArray("image");
```

Hope this will help you.